# Eclipse ADT - Android 4.2.2 sample project contain hundreds of errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, sample

I'm a beginner in Android programming and trying to look at the sample projects,
from the `Eclipse ADT (v21.1.0)` i'm choosing New Android Sample -> `4.2.2` -> and have 3 sample choices (Support4Demo,11Demo,...) each of them have 100+ errors

most errors are `"cannot be resolved to type"` errors and overriding errors

what am i doing wrong?
I am using the latest eclipse and SDK (downloaded together)

Thanks :)

Comment: Try this right click on your project Properties>Java Compiler> Compiler Compliance Level> Set it to 1.5 or 1.6 apply.

Comment: just Clean and Build your project

Comment: Tried both, still same errors...

Comment: This kind of thing can often be resolved by adding the proper jar files.  Since you are still new, you may want to start slower.  Just do a basic project, that prints hello world.  There are many examples on YouTube.

Comment: I already did hello world and all the activity tutorials, and ready to continue into basic fragments, and i understood that there are good samples in the Sample Projects for that, how do i fix the sample projects? (and why are they broken in the first place - they are supposed to be a good example of how to actually do something...)

Comment: If you know of other - working samples i can use, that would be great , everyone just gives references for those ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching i found that the latest revision (#12 from Feb 2013) of the Android Support Library doesn't contain some classes that it should have (FragmentTabHost, and a few more)

tried to delete and download again, and again it didn't contain the classes it should,

I found this link to the previous release (if you want a different release you can just change the number - 01,02...,09,10,11,12)

http://dl.google.com/android/repository/support_r11.zip

I replaced the support folder, copied the new (older) jar , and that solved all the problems.

Answer (score 0):

please check the version of SDK android which you work with it in the project ,
check the path of the SDK Android , and the version of the JDK .
just only these option .

good luck